# Cpanel email alternative

Tags: email, hosted

I usually recommend to my clients use the cpanel default email service, but usually it is not enough and I want to know in addition to g-suite what other email service provider can I use and if is there any for free?

Thank you

Comment: I dont know if i really understood what you want. What exactly are the characteristics that your clients found insufficient? (quantity of mailboxes, size of mailbox, customizations capabilities, etc).

Comment: They usually complain about the lack of personalization and power (understand power as the ability to send many emails in a single day) normally I recommend g-suite since I think it meets what they expect, thank you for your interest, but @user9811991 give the answer that i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yandex Mail for domain](https://connect.yandex.com/pdd/) (Russia-based, but available in English) is free with 1,000 mailboxes of unlimited size (more mailboxes are available upon request).

[Microsoft Office 365](https://products.office.com/) (paid) has domain email available on its business plans.

Comment: That was just what I needed, thanks @user9811991